# R package with CRAN and Bioconductor dependencies

Tags: r, package, bioconductor, cran

I have an R package stored on a local git server. This package has a series of dependecies - packages from both CRAN and [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/). Using the `devtools` package, I can install from git directly:

```
library(devtools)
install_git("http://mygitserver.com/username/reponame")
```

I have noticed that this installation process fails to install all of the Bioconductor dependencies, but all of the CRAN dependencies are installed correctly.

How can I set up the package's dependencies (in the `DESCRIPTION` file) so that all of the Bioconductor package dependencies are also installed correctly. I've noticed this is not a problem when the packages are hosted on a Bioconductor mirror and installed via `biocLite()`, which suggests that perhaps I could resolve this by listing a set of mirrors for `install.packages()` to search through before declaring that the package cannot be found. Is there a way to get all of these dependencies automatically?

Comment: give `setRepositories(ind=1:2)` a try.

Comment: Looks like this solves the problem. Why does this work? Is it specifying a "path" of repos (ie. CRAN and/or Bioconductor)?

Comment: See my answer below for the "why it works"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer:
`setRepositories(ind=1:2)`

tl;dr

The documentation for `setRepositories` tells us that the "default list of known repositories is stored in the file 'R_Home/etc/repositories'".  We can track this down a couple of ways, but for convenience, let's read the table of repositories into R (this will cut off all of the commented documentation in that file, but you can pull that up with `readLines` if you're interested.

```
read.table(file.path(R.home(), "etc", "repositories"), sep = "\t")

                             menu_name                                 URL default source win.binary mac.binary
CRAN                              CRAN                              @CRAN@    TRUE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
BioCsoft                 BioC software                %bm/packages/%v/bioc   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
BioCann                BioC annotation     %bm/packages/%v/data/annotation   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
BioCexp                BioC experiment     %bm/packages/%v/data/experiment   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
BioCextra                   BioC extra               %bm/packages/%v/extra   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
CRANextra                CRAN (extras)  http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
Omegahat                      Omegahat           http://www.omegahat.org/R   FALSE   TRUE      FALSE      FALSE
R-Forge                        R-Forge        http://R-Forge.R-project.org   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
rforge.net                  rforge.net               http://www.rforge.net   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
CRANextra[https]  CRAN (extras, https) https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
R-Forge[https]         R-Forge [https]       https://R-Forge.R-project.org   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
rforge.net[https]   rforge.net [https]              https://www.rforge.net   FALSE   TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
```

Imagine that each row has an index number.  When you call `setRepositories(ind = 1:2)` you are telling R to look at the repositories in rows 1 and 2.

Comment: I've noticed that some annotation packages, such as [`org.Hs.eg.db`](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/org.Hs.eg.db.html) are not found even after specifying `setRepositories(ind=1:5)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where is the guarantee that BioCsoft would always stay on the position 2?! It looks like some magic number for me that could change any day in the future...

Answer (score 1):

A different answer for github repositories is to use `biocLite()`

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("username/reposname")
```

which dispatches to devtools for github packages, and to CRAN / Bioconductor for others.

The `source()` command installs or updates the BiocInstaller package, so a variation when your version of BiocInstaller is current is

```
BiocInstaller::biocLite("username/reposname")
```

To use devtools for your exmaple, but with the correct Bioconductor repositories for your version of R and Bioconductor

```
install_git("http://mygitserver.com/username/reponame", 
            repos=BiocInstaller::biocinstallRepos())
```

The `repos` argument is eventually passed to `install.packages()`. More specifically, for me I have

```
> biocinstallRepos()
                                               BioCsoft 
           "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/bioc" 
                                                BioCann 
"https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/data/annotation" 
                                                BioCexp 
"https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/data/experiment" 
                                              BioCextra 
          "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/extra" 
                                                   CRAN 
                             "https://cran.rstudio.com"
```

with the annotation packages at the second, BioCann, url.

Comment: This is also a good solution, but, as with the one already suggested, it apparently omits `org.Hs.eg.db`. Any idea why? When I run `install.packages("org.Hs.eg.db", repos=BiocInstaller::biocinstallRepos())` I'm able to get the package.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible, i.e., provide a url to a non-github hosted package that Depends or Imports org.Hs.eg.db? I updated my response with a bit more information